# Slide In and Out a View in the same way of a Fragment Transaction does

Tags: android, android-animation

On Android there's a nice built-in animation for fragments you can easily achieve with 1 line of code:

```
transaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

I wanna achieve the same result, but on a View, to animate it every time I refresh it and change its content. I tried with

```
view.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx, android.R.anim.slide_out_right));      
view.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx, android.R.anim.slide_in_left));
```

But only one animation plays on the view, it doesn't achieve the same effect where one slide out and the other (or the same, in this case) slides in, you can clearly see half of the screen going white with my code, while Fragment Transaction's animation shows both fragments going in and out. Any way to play those two animations concurrently?

Comment: slind_in_from_left should be on the entering view, and the sile_out_to_right on the exiting view

Comment: The view is the same. What I'm trying to achieve is playing the two animations concurrently, so the same view goes out from right and in from left at the same time, like two identical view are placed next to each other and just slide to right.

Comment: That's impossible, you need a second view for entering.. if you have only one, you need to move it out of screen, update it, and move it in screen, but that will leave a empty screen while all thats happen

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve that using [AnimationSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet).

In your case the code should look like:

```
    Animation anim1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
    Animation anim2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);

    AnimationSet animationSet = new AnimationSet(false);
    animationSet.addAnimation(anim1);
    animationSet.addAnimation(anim2);
    animationSet.setDuration(1000); // 1s
    animationSet.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    view.startAnimation(animationSet);
```

Comment: Sadly, no. That's not the same effect of the Fragment's transaction animation. The two animations get played together and just flashes the view instead of smoothly sliding it out from right and in from left.

Comment: @Cusy That's because the `AnimationSet` misses the duration and interpolation, can you try with the edited answer?

Comment: Still far from what I'm trying to achieve. With the edited answer the screen goes white for some reasons, then I see the view moving and it finally flashes to the final position. What I'm trying to achieve is move a single view out and in at the same time, like there was two identical view are placed next to each other sliding to right.